# How to copy a pre-existing Word document when a new folder is created?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro to create a folder for each e-mail containing attachments and store it's attachments.

I would like an existing Word document to be copied to every new folder created.

I tried `fileCopy`, but I can't make it work since the target is variable.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Application_Startup()

Dim ol As Outlook.Application
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
Dim i As Object
Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
Dim at As Outlook.Attachment
Dim rootfol As Outlook.Folder
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim dir As Scripting.Folder
Dim dirName As String

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

Set ol = New Outlook.Application
Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set rootfol = ns.Folders(1)
Set fol = rootfol.Folders("boîte de réception").Folders("test")

For Each i In fol.Items
    If i.Class = olMail Then
        Set mi = i
        If mi.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

           dirName = "C:\Users\chadi\OneDrive\Documents\VBA\" & Format(mi.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-nn-ss ") & Left(Replace(mi.Subject, ":", ""), 20)

           If fso.FolderExists(dirName) Then
              Set dir = fso.GetFolder(dirName)
           Else
              Set dir = fso.CreateFolder(dirName)
           End If

           For Each at In mi.Attachments
               at.SaveAsFile dir.Path & "\" & at.Filename
           Next at

        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe someone else can give you a better answer without needing more information but I need you to be more specific about the variability of this file because I cannot answer your question with VBA code.

I also do not see `FileCopy` anywhere in your example.

> **[ EDIT ]**
>
> I commented out the file selection and added new code that should work with the new information you provided.
>
> **[ IMPORTANT ]**  I assume you are using Windows.  You need to **Shift Right Click** on your Word document and select **Copy As Path**.  Then you need to **paste the path** in the new code to **completely replace** `[paste the path here]`  *If* you do it correctly it should look *something* like like `mySpecialWordDocument = "C:\MyDirectory\MyFiles\MyFile.docx"`

---

```
       If fso.FolderExists(dirName) Then
          Set dir = fso.GetFolder(dirName)
       Else
          Set dir = fso.CreateFolder(dirName)
          'With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
             '.AllowMultiSelect = False
             '.Filters.Clear
             'If .Show Then fso.CopyFile .SelectedItems(1), dirName & "\" & Split(.SelectedItems(1), "\")(UBound(Split(.SelectedItems(1), "\")))
          'End With

          Dim mySpecialWordDocument as String
          mySpecialWordDocument= [paste the path here]
          fso.CopyFile mySpecialWordDocument, dirName & "\" & Split(mySpecialWordDocument, "\")(UBound(Split(mySpecialWordDocument, "\")))

       End If
```

It opens a dialog window for the user to select a file and copies that file into the new folder.

For me to answer the question you asked, you need to tell me how you manually decide which file to select.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't use FileCopy in the code above because it wasn't working. When I said the new folder is variable, i meant that everytime I receive an e-mail, the macro will automatically create a NEW folder, Extract all the attachments of the email and place it inside this new folder. But I would also like, with every new folder created, to insert a word document inside of it. Does it make sens? Sorry for my english! I'm french!

Comment: I just used your code, and it's almost perfect. I just dont want to have to manually select the word document. I want it to be automatically copied to each new folders created!

Comment: Be specific.  Where does this Word document come from?  How do you know which Word document to copy?  Why doesn't `FileCopy` work?  Does `File Copy` give you an error?  What error is it?  I need specific information that you are not providing.

Comment: This word document is already saved on my drive. I know which one to copy because it will always be the same word document that will have to be copied in all these folders. I didn't know how to write the `FileCopy` code because I need to have a target source and I don't know how to code it. I had no error cause I did not try to properly code the `FileCopy`.

Comment: @MelanieDeschene Thank you.  I understand.  I updated the answer and it should work for you (but I admit I have not tested it).  Please note that you have to edit the code by following the instructions I provided.  It will not work unless you replace `[paste the path here]` with the actual path of your Word document.  You can easily copy and paste the path by Shift Right Clicking on the document in Windows File Explorer and selecting "Copy as Path".

Comment: I noticed a problem with this application. Whenever theres an e-mail without a subject, the macro won't work. Also, if I forward an e-mail to myself and try to run the macro, it also wont work. Any ideas why?^

Comment: @melaniedeschene from what I see: your code only runs once (when the application starts), it only looks for email messages in 1 MAPI folder ("boîte de réception\test"), and It only looks for emails with attachments.  It does not care about the subject, sender, or recipient and it won't look at that folder again until the app is restarted.  So, if your email doesn't have an attachment, you didn't move move it to that folder, and you didn't restart the app - then that would probably be the problem.  If you have done those things then the problem is probably not in the example code you provided.